# cannnot find module firebase-admin on aws ubuntu machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-admin

Here my code is as shown below:

**firebaseRealTime.js**

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

var serviceAccount = require('./../*******.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://*****.firebaseio.com/"
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref();

exports.setData = function(orderID, foodTruck, orderStatus) {
    var usersRef = ref.child(foodTruck);
    usersRef.child(orderID).set({
        order_status : orderStatus
    });

}
```

and the directory structure of this file is **projectname/config/firebaseRealtime.js**

and path for **service.json** is **projectname/service.json**

Now this code works fine when I am testing it on windows local machine. But I run the same code on aws ubuntu machine, it gives me error **cannot find module firebase-admin**.

why this code is giving different result on different machine?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install firebase-admin`?

Comment: yes, it worked. I am using yarn as dependency manager. I tried to install it with sudo yarn install. still it gave me the error.

Comment: Make sure `firebase-admin` is in the `dependencies` property of your `package.json` and do an `npm install` or `yarn install` on the AWS box.